# Help with a propositional logic question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question goes like this:

For each of the arguments below, formalize them in a propositional logic. If the argument is valid identify which inference rule was used, and formulate the tautology underlying the rule. If the argument is invalid, state whether the inverse or converse error was made (<-- huh what's that )

D) All students who do not do their homework and do not study the course material will not get a good course grade.
John gets a good course grade.
Therefore John did his homework or studied the course material

---

Where I did this:

p(x): student who does h/w
c(x): student who studies 
d(x): get a good course grade

1. $ ∀x( ¬ P(x) ^  ¬ C(x) )  -> ¬ d(x) $  Premise
2. $(¬ P(John) ^ ¬ C(John))  -> ¬ d (john) $ Universal instatation
3. $ ¬ (¬ P(John) ^ ¬ c(john)) ∨  ¬ d (john) $    DeMorgan

I'm stuck because at this point the answer wont make sense, because I'll have an or not an and as a conclucion ( plus d will be not get a good course grade if I see this right.)

Any help?

Comment: Please, note that this is not *propositional logic*, but *predicate* logic.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) for : *contrapositive*, *inverse* and *converse*. I think that "converse error" means trying to infer $Q \to P$ from $P \to Q$ (that is incorrect) and the same for "inverse error".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~grahne/comp232/assgn2.pdf the assignment in question.  Furthermore, Propositional logic is exactly what I did there ( according to wiki and other website) using inference law which is what I've been taught

Comment: I see ... but if so, in propositional logic we cannot write : $\forall x \ldots$. Thus we have to rewrite the problem as : $(\lnot P \land \lnot C) \to \lnot D, D_j \vdash P_j \lor C_j$. But now $D$ and $D_j$ are different *propositional letters* and the argument is not *valid* any more.

Comment: In any case, the proof below, after the initial step of *Universal Instantiation* is all propositional; thus it can be the right answer...

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know you couldn't use universal quantifier with propositional logic as you can use rule of inference with both cases. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $∀x[(¬P(x) \land ¬C(x)) \to ¬D(x)]$ --- Premise

2) $D(John)$ --- premise

3) $(¬P(John) \land ¬C(John)) \to ¬D(John)$ --- from 1) by *Universal Instantiation*

4) $D(John) \to \lnot (¬P(John) \land ¬C(John))$ --- from 3) by [Transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(logic))

5) $\lnot (¬P(John) \land ¬C(John))$ --- from 4) by [Modus Ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)

> 6) $P(John) \lor C(John)$ --- form 5) by [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

---

But you can prove it also with you approach :

> 3) $¬(¬P(John) \land ¬C(john)) \lor \lnot D(john)$ --- by [Material Implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

4) $(P(John) \lor C(john)) \lor \lnot D(john)$ --- from 3) by *De Morgan*

> 5) $P(John) \lor C(john)$ --- from 2nd premise : $D(John)$ by [Disjunctive Syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism).

Comment: does a contraposition mean a "converse error"? and thank you by the way :)